# Codeigniter - Format date in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

Is it possible to format the following date in an active record where clause?

I need to format `channel_titles.entry_date` to be in the format `Y-m-d`, like the `$yesterday` variable.

```
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday'));

$this->db->where('channel_titles.entry_date', $yesterday);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` function like that:

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(channel_titles.entry_date), '%Y-%m-%d')", $yesterday, false);
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, then realised that the date is saved as a timestamp. Is there a way to format it still?

Comment: @ccdavies Answer updated with `from_unixtime` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(channel_titles.entry_date,'%Y-%m-%d') ", $yesterday);
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, then realised that the date is saved as a timestamp. Is there a way to format it still?